# pre order of binary search tree, errors, not sure what error is

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

this function is inside of binary tree class

```
/***********************
 *
* give preorder of tree
*
* ********************/

void preorder(Node * node, std::ostream &p_str){
    if(node != NULL){

            //p_str << node->Data() << " ";

            if(node->m_ll) {

                    preorder(node->m_ll, &p_str);

            }

            if(node->m_rl) {

                    preorder(node->m_rl, &p_str);
            }
    }
 }
```

which makes a call here outside of class. to recursively traverse the tree, starting with root

```
void preorder(Node * node, std::ostream &p_str){
    if(node != NULL){

            //p_str << node->Data() << " ";

            if(node->m_ll) {

                    preorder(node->m_ll, &p_str);

            }

            if(node->m_rl) {

                    preorder(node->m_rl, &p_str);
            }
    }
 }
```

I'm getting errors like

```
Tree.h:337: error: no matching function for call to       'CTree<int>::preorder(CTree<int>::Node*&, std::ostream*)'
Tree.h:330: note: candidates are: void CTree<T>::preorder(CTree<T>::Node*, std::ostream&) [with T = int]
 Tree.h:343: error: no matching function for call to 'CTree<int>::preorder(CTree<int>::Node*&, std::ostream*)'
 Tree.h:330: note: candidates are: void CTree<T>::preorder(CTree<T>::Node*, std::ostream&) [with T = int]
```

any idea of the fairly simple thing i'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preorder(node->m_ll, &p_str);` should be `preorder(node->m_ll, p_str);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the address `ostream` object. The function is taking a *reference*, not a pointer:

```
preorder(node->m_rl, p_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects the argument by reference, but `&p_str` is a pointer.

Simply call `preorder(node->m_ll, p_str);`.